# Powershell - Inexplicable timeout for HttpRequests

Tags: powershell, httprequest, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script that monitors several pages on a handful of servers. It gives the HTTP status code from each to determine the server's health.

This has been working perfectly for a number of weeks but today, without making any changes to the script, I started receiving timeout errors ("The operation has timed out"). A telnet on port 80 to the server let me through instantly and I could connect happily via every other mechanism I could think of.

Finally I updated the script by changing the timeout period from 1000ms to 2000ms and the script worked again, instantly. And it still worked after I changed it back to 1000ms.

This is the second time something like this has happened with the same resolution. What is happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Is your script running permanently (in a continuous loop) or is it scheduled? Might the change that worked in the time-out period just be a side effect of the fact that you restarted your script?

Comment: This sounds like you are not closing your connections, I think David is right, the side-effect of editing the script would be to clean up your connections.

Comment: I can see where you are going but sadly the script is run on demand and the issue survives closing and opening a new powershell session (as a different user). Also I am explicitly closing the response whether or not an error occurs.

Comment: I wonder if you are hitting the MaxServicePoint connection limit, telnet may use a different connection point if your connections are not identical.  This blog gives some information on how to monitor service points: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

Comment: I had the same issue. It is weird. I can get to the url using postman or curl.

Comment: I ended up using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 and it worked. I still don't know what the issue was but none of the .NET tricks worked.

Answer (score 0):

This script may help, it may be a bit overkill for your situation.

```
function HTTP-Get() {
    param
    (
        [string] $target
    )

    try
    {
        $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($target)
        $webRequest.Method = "GET"

        [System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
        $rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();

        [System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
        [string] $results = $sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    catch [System.Net.WebException] 
    {
        Write-Warning $_
        if ($_.response)
        {
            $_.response.Close();    
        }
    }

    finally
    {
        if ($sr)
        {
            $sr.close();
            $sr.dispose();
        }
        if ($resp)
        {
            $resp.close();
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Hi David, this is almost exactly what I am doing already except that I am setting the method to HEAD, I don't allow redirects and I'm not consuming the response stream.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments: I had this issue with powershell and none of the .NET http tricks worked (httprequest, webclient). The site I used worked fine with postman and other http helpers.

It seemed like the issue is related to the .NET version, sp, etc. I changed my code to use COM instead of .NET and now it works fine.

```
......

$HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER = 0
$Http = new-object -com "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1"
$Http.open("GET", "http://....", $false)

$Http.SetCredentials($userName, $password, $HttpREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER) 

$Http.send()
$status = [int]$Http.Status
$responseText = $Http.responseText

.....
```

I hope it helps :)